# Putting two links and a text string into a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, excel-2007, line-breaks

I would like a cell like this:

> Change
>
> 20:25
>
> to
>
> 20:30

where the two different times (20:25, 20:30) are sourced from two different cells. I would like to preserve the line breaks.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: There is no formula. I only know how to source data a la `=A1`. The text looks the way it is now. I want to get the `20:25` part from one cell, and `20:30` from another.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to source the two different times (20:25,20:30) from two different cells. What I meant with the line breaks is, that I want the final result to look like the one I have above. Meaning that each piece of "text" goes on a separate line.

Comment: Can you re-explain. It's still not clear. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the layout as in the image, please try:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1 &CHAR(10) & C1 & CHAR(10) &D1
```

[image: SO19145155 example]

Alternatively:

```
="Change" & CHAR(10) & B1 & CHAR(10) & "to" & CHAR(10) & D1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand. The issue here is having the line breaks in a single cell? If so, you can use `ALT+Enter` to put in line breaks for Excel. http://help.isu.edu/index.php?action=knowledgebase&catid=38&subcatid=66&docid=1022

Edit: This may work with what you're trying to do:

`="Change " & TEXT(A1,"h:mm") & " to " & TEXT(A2,"h:mm")`

The `TEXT` function may be needed if Excel is trying to convert your date to a number.

Comment: Hi Ant. No the issue is that I know that if I want to retrieve data from a cell, I will do something like `=A100`. However, how do I do this, when the formula `=A100` is in the middle of other text?

Comment: I see now. You should be able to get around this by right clicking the cell > "Format Cells" > Under the Alignment Tab > Check the "Wrap Text" checkbox. Hopefully that should fix it.

Comment: Hmm okay, and what would the formula for the cell look like then? `Change '=A1' to '=A2'`? That's my main question.

Comment: Try this: ="Change " & TEXT(A1,"h:mm") & " to " & TEXT(A2,"h:mm")